# Column privileges in a GRANT

Tags: mysql, sql

Take the following from [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html):

**Column Privileges**

Column privileges apply to single columns in a given table. Each privilege to be granted at the column level must be followed by the column or columns, enclosed within parentheses.

```
GRANT SELECT (col1), INSERT (col1, col2) ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

How would an `INSERT` work if there were more columns in the table than the user has access to? For example, if there are three columns, would the insert evaluate `col3` to NULL, or how would that work?

Comment: My guess is it will use the column's default value, which is `NULL` if not specified explicitly. Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: That seems like the only thing that makes sense. Something has to be put into the other columns, and when you don't specify a column in an `INSERT` statement it gets the default.